# Ambari 2.8.0 failed install bigtop 3.2.0 when installing bigtop-select

Tags: ambari, bigtop

error exists when installing bigtop 3.2.0 on ambari 2.8.0 , i'm using ambari 2.8.0 from github

url ambari :
https://github.com/apache/ambari/archive/refs/tags/release-2.8.0-rc1.zip

and installing the bigtop using public repo of bigtop 3.2.0

url bigtop :
http://repos.bigtop.apache.org/releases/3.2.0/centos/7/x86_64

the error exist when the first installation where the bigtop-select is not provided by public repo of bigtop 3.2.0

> 2023-06-08 07:10:12,873 - Reporting component version failed
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 370, in execute
> self.save_component_version_to_structured_out(self.command_name)
> File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 228, in save_component_version_to_structured_out
> stack_select_package_name = stack_select.get_package_name()
> File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/functions/stack_select.py", line 115, in get_package_name
> package = get_packages(PACKAGE_SCOPE_STACK_SELECT, service_name, component_name)
> File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/functions/stack_select.py", line 232, in get_packages
> supported_packages = get_supported_packages()
> File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/functions/stack_select.py", line 153, in get_supported_packages
> raise Fail("Unable to query for supported packages using {0}".format(stack_selector_path))
> Fail: Unable to query for supported packages using /usr/lib/bigtop-select/distro-select
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stack-hooks/before-INSTALL/scripts/hook.py", line 37, in 
> BeforeInstallHook().execute()
> File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 355, in execute
> method(env)
> File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stack-hooks/before-INSTALL/scripts/hook.py", line 33, in hook
> install_packages()
> File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stack-hooks/before-INSTALL/scripts/shared_initialization.py", line 37, in install_packages
> retry_count=params.agent_stack_retry_count)
> File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/base.py", line 166, in **init**
> self.env.run()
> File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 160, in run
> self.run_action(resource, action)
> File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 124, in run_action
> provider_action()
> File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/providers/packaging.py", line 30, in action_install
> self._pkg_manager.install_package(package_name, self.__create_context())
> File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/ambari_commons/repo_manager/yum_manager.py", line 219, in install_package
> shell.repository_manager_executor(cmd, self.properties, context)
> File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/ambari_commons/shell.py", line 759, in repository_manager_executor
> raise RuntimeError(message)
> RuntimeError: Failed to execute command '/usr/bin/yum -y install bigtop-select', exited with code '1', message: 'Error: Nothing to do
> '

Answer (score 0):

missing bigtop-select-pkg package,you can build with ./gradlew bigtop-select-pkg

Answer (score 0):

You have to build the Bigtop 3.2.0 using the below reference and it's working with ambari 2.8.0.

major issues:

> When you restart the HDFS through ambari UI -datanodes itself register with new cluster ID.(start through cmd)
> Phoenix is not available.
> Apache Ranger UI is not available.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Installation+Guide+for+Ambari+2.8.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fELuZ.png)